# How to remove this chainwheel?

Tags: bottom-bracket, electric-bike

I'm trying to replace the motor but I'm unable to remove the chain wheel and bike(batavus wayz e-go 2019).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried a big adjustable spanner?

On a more serious note, it may well have a left-hand thread like the Bosch units do.

If so, that would loosen when turned clockwise. And you would need a chain whip to hold the chainwheel in opposing force.

Comment: Left hand thread sounds exactly what it is - good spotting.   If OP can see any of the thread at all, that might be enough of a clue.  Heat and differential cooling can break parts loose, and leverage is always good as long as there's a vise holding things securely.   A suitably-sized socket also makes more sense than an adjustable spanner.

Answer (score 5):

If what is meant by "chainwheel" is the chainring, then it should be removed by unscrewing these four bolts:

[image: Chainring bolt]

You may need to use two appropriately sized hex keys, or a hex key and a flat screwdriver (or similar tool) to hold the pieces of these bolt assemblies when unscrewing them.

It is hard to understand what the big bolt in the middle holds, and why it is so scratched. Possibly it holds the chainring spider (the part that the chainring is attached to)?

More pictures explaining the configuration might help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually, I want to remove the middle hex nut which is attached to the motor, and I didn't find any tool for that. there are different types of lockring but didn't find any guide to removing hex nut.  

unscrewing the 4 screws you mention will, not do anything because I want to remove the motor not chainring.

Comment: One more thing, the big bolt has scratched because I was trying to remove it with different tools.

Comment: @RahulPatil Isn't that thing you're calling a "hex nut" just a regular 6-sided nut? I think you just need to figure out what size it is, and find an appropriate wrench/spanner/nut drive/socket bit for it, and then figure out if it needs to rotate clockwise or counter-clockwise (not all bolts on bikes are CCW to loosen). If you've tried some socket bits and found they don't work because of the big four-sided axel bit sticking up in the middle, they're just not deep enough. You'd need either a wrench, which won't care about the axel sticking out, or a deeper socket.

Comment: @RahulPatil Further to my comment, I'm assuming that nut sticks up far enough beyond the surrounding metal to get a grip on it with a wrench. The scracthes you've created may be a hint that it doesn't. Can you post a picture that's not straight down the barrel of the axel? Maybe 45 deg angle from the side of the axel? If that nut is recessed below the face of the surrounding metal, then you need to use a socket bit that's the correct size, but also thin-walled enough to drop down into that channel around the nut.

Comment: I think, @SSilk, your last point is right - a thin-walled socket is required.  The scratches look to me like someone's been going at it with a nasty cheap stamped multi-spanner, though those don't usually go as big as this nut must be